# Handwritten note in chinese (Characters identified: 阳台还有衣服)

Tags: character-identification, handwriting

A chinese visitor left this note on my door.
If it was typed, i'd easily find the meaning. But it is handwritten!
Would you guys help me to understand it, please?

Thanks!
[image: Note]

Comment: Your balcony still has clothes on/in it.

Answer (score 4):

It says

> 阳台还有衣服
>   <sub>Yángtái háiyǒu yīfu</sub>

This directly translates to "balcony still has clothes".  More specifically:

- [阳台](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E9%98%B3%E5%8F%B0) (yángtái) = balcony (or something similar, like a veranda)
- [还有](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%BF%98%E6%9C%89) (háiyǒu) = still has (in this context)
- [衣服](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%A1%A3%E6%9C%8D) (yīfú) = clothes

Comment: Is handwriting like this normal in china to the extent that natives find this easy to read, or is this an exceptional case? You'd think that people would make their hand writing more legible in a language like mandarin where theres thousands of different squiggles to differentiate between rather than 26

Comment: @小奥利奥 Looks decently neat to me, at least for a scribbled note. Handwriting doesn't look like printed block typefaces in any language.